# PayPal error 10413 - The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts

Tags: paypal, shopping-cart

I send the following request to PayPal:

```
USER=APIUSERNAME&  
PWD=APIPASSWORD&
SIGNATURE=APISIGNATURE&
METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&
VERSION=204&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=SALE&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=1.11&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=EUR&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM=148&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC=PayPal+Express+Checkout&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM=145001530&
RETURNURL=returnurl&
CANCELURL=cancelurl&
EMAIL=email%40live.nl&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME=Testperson-nl+Approved&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET=Neherkade+1XI&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY=Gravenhage&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP=2521VA&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=NL&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM=0612345678&
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Jackie+O+Round+Sunglasses&
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=1.11&
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=ace001&
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1&
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0=0.19&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=0.19
```

However for some reason i get the following message:

> L_ERRORCODE0=10413&
>       L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.&
>       L_LONGMESSAGE0=The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.

I tried many different configs (adding item amount without tax etc).
Well, anyone can help me know what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT = (Total amount user have to pay)

```
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT= Everything including Tax,shipping cost, insurance etc
```